# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() the same error remains

Tags: android, flutter

Using the [Firebase Auth package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#firebase-auth-for-flutter), I'm receiving the following error:

```
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

[image: the error message]

This happens even after initializing Firebase
[image: even after initializing firebase]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I got the solution,
Visit flutterfire website and follow that documentation.
Just wrap the future builder widget into a material app widget and you are good to go

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `Firebase.initializeApp()`.
**It returns a `future`, so you need to add `await`.**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

This depends on the `firebase_core`, so you need to import it in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
     sdk: flutter

  firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
```

> Before any of the Firebase services can be used, FlutterFire needs to be initialized (you can think of this process as FlutterFire "bootstrapping" itself). The initialization step is asynchronous, meaning you'll need to prevent any FlutterFire related usage until the initialization is completed.

> To initialize FlutterFire, call the initializeApp method on the Firebase class: await Firebase.initializeApp(); The method is asynchronous and returns a Future, so you need to ensure it has completed before displaying your main application.

[Reference](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initializing-flutterfire)

Comment: Even after adding the `await` keyword to ensure that the initialization has completed?

Comment: yes i havent mentioned it in the code that I have sent as a link,

Comment: But actually in the flutter fire website they have given a different documentation only
I shall try it today

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you added the `firebase_core` package in `pubspec.yaml`.

```
firebase_core : ^0.5.0+1
```

Comment: i have imported them

Answer (score 1):

1. Add to the following to the `pubspec.yaml` file:

   `firebase_core: ^0.5.0`
2. Add the following to the  `main.dart` file:

   ```dart
   import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

   void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MyApp());
   }
   ```